# Searching words start and end with the same character with Linux grep command

Tags: text-processing, grep

How can I search for words that start and end with the same character in a file by using the Linux **grep** command? I have tried some answers but they didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: "_I have tried some answers but they didn't work_" - next time please show us what you've tried. You might have been really close to a solution and we can build on your ideas to reach something that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input contains a single word per line, you may use

```bash
grep -x '\(.\).*\1' file
```

... to extract all lines that start and end with the same character.  This is done by capturing the first character on the line using `\(.\)`, allowing the rest of the characters on the line to be anything (with `.*`) but then forcing a match of the captured character at the very end using the back-reference `\1`.

The `-x` option to `grep` tells the utility that the pattern must match across a complete line, not just a part of the line.  Without `-x`, you would have to insert explicit anchors in the regular expression to be sure you match complete lines: `^\(.\).*\1$`

Example run on my system's dictionary, showing only the 5 first results:

```bash
$ grep -x '\(.\).*\1' /usr/share/dict/words | head -n 5
aa
aba
abaca
abasia
abepithymia
```

If you're dealing with input that contains multiple space-delimited words on each line, then you may pre-process that text by splitting it into one word per line first.  Here, I additionally convert all characters to lower-case with `tr` at the same time as replacing spaces with newlines, and I remove duplicates by means of `sort -u`:

```bash
tr ' [:upper:]' '\n[:lower:]' <file | sort -u | grep -x '\(.\).*\1'
```

Note that this ignores the fact that an "ordinary text" may contain punctuation and other characters that are not part of words.

---

It is pointed out in comments (now deleted) that the `grep` command misses single-letter words, which technically starts and end with the same character.

To get these too:

```bash
grep -x -e '\(.\).*\1' -e . file
```

This now returns lines starting and ending with the same character or lines only containing a single character.

Comment: What about using `awk` and use split or substr for every line? So I can compare the first character with the last one, is it slower perhaps?

Comment: Great answer, I thought it was not possible to use `grep`  in this case, but I see I was wrong :).

Comment: @EdgarMagallon Sure, you can do that, but it's going to be a bit more fiddly, more code. I would probably not do that, unless I had to do it as part of an existing `awk` program.

Comment: Thank you. I also tried '^(\w).*\1$'. Seems it works too. Are there many ways to capture the first character? What is the difference between \\(.\\) and (\w)?

Comment: @newlearner `\w` is a Perl-compatible pattern that some `grep` implementations know about, which is the same as the more standard `[[:alnum:]_]`.  It matches alphanumerics (and the underscore).  The dot matches any character.  I used a dot since you specified "character" in the question.  Also, I'm assuming you used `\(\w\)`, not `(\w)`?

Comment: @Kusalananda I used it in grep -E '^(\w).*\1$'. I found that it is ok with -E but invalid back reference without -E. Why is this so?

Comment: @newlearner `\(...\)` is a group in a basic regular expression. `(...)` is a group in an extended regular expression.  With `-E` you switch to extended regular expressions.  However, also note that using back-references in extended regular expressions actually isn't standard, so if you rely on the non-standard `\w` _and_ on using back-references (`\1`) with `grep -E`, then your command may possibly work on your machine, but it may not work on everybody else's systems. Oh, and `-E` is not (yet) a standard option to `grep` in the first place.

Comment: @newlearner I mean, it'll possibly work on _most_ systems, but you're using several non-standard bits and pieces that I personally think are not necessary. But that's mostly my personal opinion based on my experience of writing shell scripts for many types of Unix systems.

Comment: @newlearner Yes, you may ask that, in a separate question (if it hasn't been asked before, I haven't checked). That way we allow others to answer too.

Answer (score 1):

If by *word*, you mean any sequence of one or more non-whitespace characters, with GNU `grep` you could do:

```
grep -Po '(?<!\S)(?=(\S))\S*\1(?!\S)' your-file
```

That matches on sequences of 0 or more non-whitespace characters (`\S*`) that end in the same non-whitespace character (`\1`) as was captured (`(\S)`) in a look-ahead operator (`(?=...)`) at the start, using negative look-behind (`(?<!...)`) and look-ahead (`(?!...)`) operators on either side to make sure the found word is neither preceded nor followed by non-whitespace characters.

In this answer, it finds:

```
'(?<!\S)(?=(\S))\S*\1(?!\S)'
sequences
0
that
a
```

It also finds `That` if you add the `-i` option.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne '.put if m:i/ ^ (.) .*? $0 $ /;'  file
```

File is read linewise using the `-ne` non-autoprinting command line flags. Captures in Raku are denoted by `(`…`)` parentheses, and start from `$0`. The match is made case-insensitive with the `:i` adverb.

```
~$ cat /usr/share/dict/words | raku -e 'my @a; @a.push($_) if / ^ (.) .*? $0 $ / for $*IN.lines; .put for @a.elems;'
9917
```

(Remove the call to `elems` above to return a list of matching words).

https://raku.org