# How to search for words not containing consecutive consonants by using grep command?

Tags: text-processing, grep

`grep -Ev '[^aeiouy]{2}'` should give the answer (assuming an input with one word made of ASCII lowercase letters only per line).

However, is there a way to do it without `-v`?

Comment: Just like with [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/720108), can we assume that the input consists of lines with one word per line?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes

Comment: Why would you do it without the `-v`? Grep is a tool specifically designed to find _matches_. Its developers were nice enough to add an option that reverses the function and finds _non-matches_.  So why would you not want to use it?

Comment: I know. I am just wondering if this is possible and easy to do.

Comment: Please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/720108/searching-words-start-and-end-with-the-same-character-with-linux-grep-command#comment1365458_720108

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a positive match, you'd need to make sure that if there are consonants they are not followed nor preceded by consonants, that each consonant is preceded by either the start of the line or a vowel and followed by either then end of line or a vowel.

So:

```
v='[aeiouy]' c='[^aeiouy]'
grep -xE "($c?$v)*$c?"
```

```
$ grep -cxE "($c?$v)*$c?" /usr/share/dict/words
11353
$ grep -cvE "$c$c" /usr/share/dict/words
11353
$ diff -s <(grep -xE "($c?$v)*$c?" /usr/share/dict/words) <(grep -vE "$c{2}" /usr/share/dict/words)
Files /proc/self/fd/11 and /proc/self/fd/18 are identical
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
raku -ne '.put unless m:i/ <-[aeiouy]> ** 2 /;'

#OR

raku -ne '.put unless m:i/ <[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]> ** 2 /;'
```

An alternative in case the OP encounters Unicode that the posted `grep` solutions cannot handle. According to recent MacOS (BSD?) grep man page: *"The grep utility does not normalize Unicode input, so a pattern containing composed characters will not match decomposed input, and vice versa."* (Raku is reported to normalize Unicode input: see URL below).

Comparing the two different solutions above. Note it is necessary to use a `:i` case-insensitive match, to get identical results:

```
~$ raku -ne 'state $i; ++$i unless m:i/ <-[aeiouy]> ** 2 /; END $i.say;' /usr/share/dict/words
38048
~$ raku -ne 'state $i; ++$i unless m:i/ <[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]> ** 2 /; END $i.say;' /usr/share/dict/words
38048
```

```
~$ diff -s <(raku -ne '.put unless m:i/ <-[aeiouy]> ** 2 /;' /usr/share/dict/words) <(raku -ne '.put unless m:i/ <[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]> ** 2 /;' /usr/share/dict/words)
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 are identical
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/unicode
https://raku.org